# Mercurial Bisect: abort: inconsistent state, <changeset> is good and bad

Tags: mercurial, bisect

A bug has been introduced in the code base I'm working on and I'm attempting to see which changset introduced it. Here's what I've done so far:

Cloned the release branch

```
$ hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/
```

Marked the tip as bad

```
$ hg bisect --bad
```

Marked the last working changeset I'm aware of working as good

```
$ hg bisect --good 5500ee2a6206
abort: starting revisions are not directly related
```

What does this error mean? I'm not quite sure I understand what it's saying. If I run the command once more I get a different message:

```
$ hg bisect --good 5500ee2a6206
abort: inconsistent state, 275567:5500ee2a6206 is good and bad
```

I've only marked it as good, how can it be bad as well?

Comment: It means that the change-sets marked by you are not in the same branch.